# How to implement load more Pagination(infinite scrolling) on RecyclerView using data from Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement *load more pagination(infinite scrolling)*. I am getting data from **Firebase realtime database**.

The data is being used in **RecyclerView**.

As the user scrolls I want to load 10 more items when he reach the end of the recyclerView.

I tried to find solution on the internet, but didn't find any.

Here's my MainActivity :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<CoffeeItem> coffeeItems;
    private CoffeeAdapter coffeeAdapter;
    private Context context = MainActivity.this;
    static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    GridLayoutManager manager;
    private int currentPage = 1;
    private static final int TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD = 10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        manager = new GridLayoutManager(this,2);

        coffeeItems = new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(manager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                loadMoreData();
            }
        });

        init();

    }


    private void init() {

        clearAll();

        Query query = reference.child("Images");
        query.limitToFirst(TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD);
        query.startAt(currentPage*TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD);

        query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    CoffeeItem coffeeItem = new CoffeeItem();

                    coffeeItem.setUrl(snapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());
                    coffeeItem.setDescription(snapshot.child("description").getValue().toString());

                    coffeeItems.add(coffeeItem);
                }


                coffeeAdapter = new CoffeeAdapter(coffeeItems, context);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(coffeeAdapter);
                recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
                coffeeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

               
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

     
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadMoreData(){
        currentPage++;
        init(); 
    }

    private void clearAll() {


        if (coffeeItems != null){
            coffeeItems.clear();
        if (coffeeAdapter != null) {
            coffeeAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }

        coffeeItems = new ArrayList<>();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work: `query.startAt(currentPage*TOTAL_ITEM_EACH_LOAD)`. Firebase queries are not based on offsets, but on knowing at what item to start.

The recipe for pagination in Firebase:

1. Order your items on their key, their value, or the value of a child property. If you have no specific ordering need, use `orderByKey()`.
2. When you process the items from the database, keep track of the value and key of the last item. If you ordered by key, you only need the key.
3. When you want to load the next page of items, pass the last value and key into `startAt`.

There are hundreds of questions already about pagination in Firebase, so I recommend checking those out: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bandroid%5D+pagination